# Floor Plan software for Mac

Tags: macos, software-recommendation

Is there a free program that can make floor plans on a Mac? Specifically, I'm looking for something that's fairly easy to use. Doesn't need to have a ton of features, just shouldn't be a headache.

Comment: with dimensions , to scale,  ect.... please be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [Lucidchart](https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/floor_plan_for_mac). I think it's pretty close to what you're looking for. Free, not a huge selection of shapes when it comes to floor plans, but very easy to use for making an office desk plan or something like that.